# Getting error while making scatter plot with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Black lines on axis and scatter plot a straight line]

Trying to make scatter plot using pyplot but getting black covered bars and the scatter is in a line rather then being scattered points. I'm trying to do kmeans on the set of data https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wholesale+customers#. And trying to show scatter plots of all pair of attributes with the cluster colouring.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('wholesale_customers.csv', delimiter=',')
ds = pd.read_csv('wholesale_customers.csv', sep=',', header=None)

ds = ds.drop([0])
ds = ds.drop(0, 1)
ds = ds.drop(1, 1)
dsT = ds.T
columns = ['fresh', 'milk', 'grocery', 'frozen', 'detergents', 'delicatessen']
for i in range(2, 8):
    mean = 0
    min = 100000
    max = 0
    temp = ds[i].values
    for x in temp:
        x = int(x)
        if x < min:
            min = x
        if x > max:
            max = x
        mean += x
    mean /= 440
    print(columns[i - 2], " min: ", min, ", max: ", max, ", mean: ", mean)

temp = ds.values
tempT = dsT.values

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
label = kmeans.fit_predict(temp)

for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(i+1, 6):
        plt.scatter(tempT[i], tempT[j])
        plt.xlabel(columns[i])
        plt.ylabel(columns[j])
        plt.show()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it looks  like your data is not in the right dtype. Instead of numerical values they probably are strings. This is why a new label is created for each value and why the data falls onto a line.